# Why my Group root is an abstract and how to fix it?

Tags: java, javafx

I am making an app with JavaFX. And this is my code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package line;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.security.acl.Group;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeLineCap;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

 /**
 *
 * @author kevin
 */

public class Line extends Application {   

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{
        Group root=new Group();
    }  

    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Why my Group root is an abstract and how to fix it?

What is abstract? How can I fix this to work properly?

Comment: `java.security.acl.Group` is an _interface_ so what you need is an implementation of that interface. To be honest, this question indicates you are very new to programming or at least Java. If that's the case then please do yourself a favor and learn the basics before diving head first into the rocky waters of ui development.

Comment: Try reading the javadocs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/acl/Group.html

Comment: `import java.awt.Color;` is going to cause problems also. Wrong import.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong class, the correct class is javafx.scene.Group ,not the Java security class.
 javafx.scene.Group can be used as root node